Why won't this function return String? instead of Future<String?>
I am relatively new to programming and I seriously don't get why this keeps happening, isn't the whole point of a future function to wait until we recieve data in the desired type?
class CardsDataBase extends ChangeNotifier {
  String folderBoxName = 'default';
  CardsDataBase(){
    folderBoxName = getBoxName();
  }
  Future<String?> getBoxName() async{
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? boxReferenceKey = prefs.getString(AppConstants.kBoxPreferenceKey);
    return boxReferenceKey;
  }
//Other stuff
}

I tried putting await before getBoxName but it won't let me because it is the constructor.
Also, is there a better way of adding this functionality?
I am trying to make it so once a user logs in with their account, a hive box opens with that user's Id. So when they log out and log back in with a different account, they have that new account's local data.
EDIT The difference of this question with other similar questions is that I am trying to use an async method inside my constructor, and I am not using a Statefull widget as there is nothing I want to build inside that class.

Constructors must be sync.  I'd suggest you wrap your async calls in a state management system, like Riverpod.

Getting a value from shared preferences is an asynchronous operation, because it may take some time to complete. There is no way to turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous operation. And there's also no way to use await in a constructor (as Randal commented).
The solution is to:

Store the shared preference in the state of your app, e.g. in a StatefulWidget.
Specify an initial value in the constructor of the widget.
Render that initial value in your UI, e.g. by showing a CircularProgressIndicator.
Update the value in the state when you get it back from the shared preferences, e.g. by calling setState.
This triggers another render, so now you can render the value instead of a progress indicator.

This is all quite extensively covered in the Flutter documentation and 3rd party tutorials, so I recommend checking the links I included above and:

Add interactivity to your Flutter app
Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await

